# Failure of server APACHE bridge oracle forms

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms, weblogic11g

i installed weblogic 11R1 and Forms developer 11g when running the forms it gave me

if i put in url

```
http://home-PC:8090/forms/frmservlet
```

> **Failure of server APACHE bridge**
>
> No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds
>   or idempotent set to OFF. Build date/time: Oct 27 2009 13:34:24 Change
>   Number: 1013

on forms builder runtime if i put

```
http://home-PC:9001/forms/frmservlet
```

and some time if i change the port the http listener might me not started or the port is already in use

here is the setting of my installation

> Type: Oracle Portal, Forms, Reports and Discoverer Installation
>   Configuration Options Middleware Home Location: C:\Oracle\fmw11g
>   Oracle Home Location: C:\Oracle\fmw11g\dev11g 
>   Oracle Instance Location: C:\Oracle\fmw11g\dev11ginst_1 
>   Oracle Instance: dev11ginst_1 Domain Option: Create Domain 
>   Domain Name: ClassicDomain 
>   Domain Home: C:\Oracle\fmw11g/user_projects/domains/ClassicDomain
>   Domain Host Name: home-PC
>   Domain Port No: 7001
>   User Name: weblogic     Automatic
>   Port Detection: true
>   Administrator Console: `http://home-PC:7001/console` 
>   EM Console: `http://home-PC:7001/em`
>   EMAgent URL: `http://home-PC:5155/emd/main`
>   Forms URL: `http://home-PC:8090/forms/frmservlet`
>   Reports URL: `http://home-PC:8090/reports/rwservlet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for my problem i solved it by copy a file

**msvcr71.dll** to windows\system directory and its might be missing because of windows updates it faced me on winxp and win7 look at [link of problem too similar](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=928362&start=0&tstart=60)

[reference 1](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1091791)

[reference 2](https://cn.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=933484)

> **Failure of server APACHE bridge**
>
> No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds
>   or idempotent set to OFF. Build date/time: Oct 27 2009 13:34:24 Change
>   Number: 1013